# Why uses scapy wrong source mac-adress with 'sendp()'

Tags: python, scapy, mac-address

I use the function `sendp()` in scapy to send some messages at layer2.
My pc has 6 LAN interfaces and I specify one interface (enp2s0f0) in `sendp()`.

When I observe the sent packets with wireshark, I can see that the source address is not from my specified interface. Instead it is from another interface of the pc.

```
 packet = Ether(dst='ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff' ,  type = 0x8011 )
 packet = packet / msg
 sendp(packet, iface='enp2s0f0')
```

The MAC-address from enp2s0f0 is `\**:\**:\**:4b:3c:00`. 
Wireshark shows the source address from the sent packet `\*\*:\**:\**:4b:3c:01`.
This is also a valid mac-address from an interface of my pc, but at this port is nothing connected.

How can I force scapy, to use the correct source-address?

Comment: Why version of Scapy are you using ? If not 2.4.3, please update & retry.

Comment: Yes, I'm using version 2.4.3

Comment: What's your platform ? Are you using libpcap mode ? (`conf.use_pcap = True`)

Comment: I have not forced to use `conf.use_pcap = True`. Will it be better to use that?

Comment: No, just report the output of `conf.use_pcap`.

Comment: ok, the output of  `conf.use_pcap` is `false`

Comment: I changed it to `True`, but also then the MAC from the sending-interface is different to the physical one.

Answer (score 0):

From reading the documentation, you could try:

```
Conf(iface='enp2s0f0')
```

Comment: Where was this in the documentation?

Comment: I found it here: https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/scapy.config.html?highlight=Conf#scapy.config.Conf.iface